# Is there any way to get three dimension pandas dataframe post pivot

Tags: python, pandas

Below if my code, Post pivoting I get a dataframe of 501 rows x 505 columns. Is it possible to get 501 rows x 101 columns **X 5 depth**  which different values corresponding to a x-axis and y-axis value accommodated in depth? basically I want to retrieve all the values (value, value_2 ..._ given a  x-axis and y-axis (for example, x-axis of 15 and y-axis of 20 should give [value, value_2, ..., value_5].
**Ideally if it could be made three dimensional were I can retrieve using x-axis, y-axis and another index for value for example 15, 20, 2 would give value for x-axis of 15, y-axis of 20 and value of value_3.**

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from itertools import product

x_axis = np.arange(0, 501)
y_axis = np.arange(0, 101)

combinations = list(product(x_axis, y_axis))

np.random.seed(42) 
values = np.random.randint(0, 11, len(combinations)) 
values_2 = np.random.randint(0, 11, len(combinations)) 
values_3 = np.random.randint(0, 11, len(combinations)) 
values_4 = np.random.randint(0, 11, len(combinations)) 
values_5 = np.random.randint(0, 11, len(combinations))

df = pd.DataFrame(combinations, columns=['x-axis', 'y-axis'])
df['value'] = values 
df['value_2'] = values_2 
df['value_3'] = values_3 
df['value_4'] = values_4 
df['value_5'] = values_5

pivot_df = df.pivot(index='x-axis', columns='y-axis')
```

Expected outcome: pivot_df to be 501 rows X 101 columns X **5 depth**
So that I can pull for example value_3 for a given x_axis and y_axis

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally if it could be made three dimensional were I can retrieve
> using x-axis, y-axis and another index for value for example `15`, `20`, `2`
> would give value for x-axis of 15, y-axis of 20 and value of value_3.

You can use :

```
val_cols = pivot_df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()

X, Y1, Y2 = 15, 20, 2

out = pivot_df.loc[X, pd.IndexSlice[val_cols[Y2], Y1]]
#returns `2`
```

---

*Old answer :*

You can [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) the [`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html#pandas.IndexSlice) made with the given `X/Y` *coordinates* :

```
X = 10
Y = 20
​
out = pivot_df.loc[[X], pd.IndexSlice[:, Y]] # `X` instead of `[X]` IYW a Series
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

       value value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5
y-axis    20      20      20      20      20
x-axis                                      
10         3       3       7       0       4
```

Comment: Repeating from the question: " Is it possible to get 501 rows x 101 columns which different values corresponding to a x-axis and y-axis value accommodated in depth?"

Comment: But you're aware that you just updated your question ?

Comment: Anyways, I updated the answer to address the second part of your question because the first one makes no sense (*at least to me*).

Comment: And regarding your repeated note: You can't ask for a `[501 rows x 101 columns]` *DataFrame* unless you specify a single coordinate in a single level (*which is the first level of columns in your case*), like so : `pivot_df.xs("value_3", axis=1, level=0) # with optional drop_level=False`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't get you. with 501 rows x 101 columns, another index/level/depth can take care of the 5 different values?

Comment: and Yes, I did update the question because I see the reference of loc which is not the answer I feel and wished to save time if anyone else is reviewing this question...

Comment: I think it would be easier if you add the exact expected output to your question and precise its type.

Comment: Sure adding/editing right away

Comment: I mean the real/explicit expected output (*that matches all the details you mention and the given input*) and not a description of it. Also, can you please explain why my updated answer does not address your problem ?

Comment: `pivot_df.xs("value_3", axis=1, level=0)` returns a `[501 rows x 101 columns]`  
 *DataFrame* and if you add `.loc[15, 20]` you will pull a specific value according to the X/Y axis. And what I put in my updated answer is just another variant.